# Installing the python3 package arcade fails with reference to pyglet-ffmpeg

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to install the python package arcade on `Linux mint 19.1 32 bit`, however its failing, could someone help or advise please?

```
sudo pip3 install arcade
```

fails with

```
...
Collecting pyglet-ffmpeg (from arcade)
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyglet-ffmpeg (from arcade) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyglet-ffmpeg (from arcade)
```

Python version is `3.6.7`
pip version is `9.1`

Comment: I have of course tried to install pyglet-ffmpeg explicitly, with sudo pip3 install pyglet-ffmpeg , and I got the same error

Comment: I have also tried upgrading pip3 to the latest version, 19.0,3 however that didn't help either.

Comment: I tried this on a different machine running 64 bit linux mint,(Same python version) and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found in my case that the problem was the path por pip was an older version of python, so unistalled the older version and reinstalled the new version (3.7.4) selecting the "add python to path" option, and then it workerd just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Works in Ubuntu

---

Install python3

```
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Make python3 as default (means use of keyword 'python' triggers python3)

```
update-alternatives --remove python /usr/bin/python2
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10
```